# Why does padding add zeros to left, but left align adds zeros to right when performing bit manipulation?

Tags: bit-manipulation, ethereum, zero-padding

I am not sure if this is a general bit manipulation related question or something specific to Ethereum. But I am reading a part of the ethereum specification [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html) and I am confused by the bit related operations.

For instance, in the [Example](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html#examples) section a uint32 value of `69` padded to `32` bytes became `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045`.

This I understand. Turn `69` to hex, which is `45` then pad it with 30 zeros.

But a value of "abc" after being *left aligned* became `0x6162630000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Now I am confused.

Why is it that the zeros here are added to the right? I understand where the 0x616263 comes from, which is the hex representation of "abc". But when padding the hex representation of `69` above, the zeros were added on the left, but with "abc" the zeros are being added on the right side. Why is this the case?

Comment: okay looks like the 32 is big endian. So the most significant byte comes first and hence goes to the left. The string on the other hand is stored as little endian, so the least significant bit comes in first and hence padding will add the zeros to the right instead

Answer (score 0):

Both are big-endian. In EVM the memory is handled in 32-byte blocks/buffers. So even if your data type is `uint8` or `uint32` it is still managed as `uint256` values (*occupies 32bytes*).

```js
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000045 == 69n
0x4500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 == 31209586552245380797759367053122912663576675554410933276260051939632835723264n
```

This is how the integers are stored, even the bits in a byte are anchored to the right:

```js
00000011 === 3
```

`Strings` are simple memory buffers, from left to right. There are some EVM-related things to remember - as with everything, the `strings` are also saved into the 32bytes blocks. So if the strings length is just 5 bytes long, you get zeros afterward. If the length is larger, then in the first block you get just the length of the string value (also right anchored as the length is `uint256`), and the blocks after that hold the actual string data.

Big-/little-endian is not just about the anchor of data, but about the byte-order:

```js
// 0x3045
// big-endian byte order
30 45
// little endian byte order
45 30
```